# Solar Charging EV

Tags: dc, charging

I am willing to connect my PV directly to my EV, without using an Inverter (losses).
There will be an MPPT controller in between.
RAV4 EV regular cable connection is J1772. The car also have a CHaDeMo port.
With 240V, the EV uses 38A thru J1772 connection.
Any ideas how to accomplish direct DC charge?

Comment: What are the specs of your PV?

Comment: The CHaDeMo port is accessible for DC charging. However there is CAN bus communication going on between the car and an external DC-charger. The car won't make contact to the battery until the charger and car has setup the communication link and negotiated the charging parameters. No easy task.

Comment: @Bruce, PV specs are configurable. Most probably, it would be around 204Vmp x 12.5A Imp, 236.5Voc x 13.6A Isc. PV temp: ~50°C. Location: California.